# How to determine if the directive of the same type already present in the list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of directives. Depending on a particular propertiy it can include directives of type A, B, C, etc. It can be any number of those directive and any combination:

```
  <li data-ng-repeat="item in items"
      data-ng-switch="item.type">
    <div data-type-a
         data-ng-switch-when="A"
         data-item="item"></div>
    <div data-type-b
         data-ng-switch-when="B"
         data-item="item"></div>
    <div data-type-c
         data-ng-switch-when="C"
         data-item="item"></div>
  </li>
```

Inside directive B I show a tooltip. In case there are 2 or more directives of type B I don't want to repeat the same tooltip, but show it only inside the first directive.

What would be the best way to do this? Can I do it inside the directive B without changing the properties of the list?

Comment: you can add a flag like data-show-tooltip="false"

Comment: it is ng-repeat, it should be true for the first encounter of directive-b, but false for the next. How would I set it?

Comment: In your controller you can determine the index of the first type-b, then in the ng-repeat you can compute the value of the flag like this `data-show-tooltip="isFirstTypeB($index)"` where `isFirstTypeB` is a function in your controller that will return **true** if $index is equal to the first type-b computed before, **false** otherwise.

Comment: This will work... but I hoped for a solution where the controller doesn't have to know about the inner life of a directive.